# In the AA setup wizard, the workstation & server page, there are count value? how is count value derived?

Tags: active-directory, contextmenu

In the AA setup wizard, the workstation & server page, there are count value? how is count value derived?

Lets say, there are three AD services configured

AD01
AD02
AD03

from which AD server, the status are pulled in the "Workstation and servers" page? how is the count numbers derived? Any idea?

Thank you,

I am trying to understand the expected design

Comment: https://exabeam.atlassian.net/browse/PLT-14317 - requested engineering to clarify the design